# What is the Python library used by Selenium to construct the ".text" attribute of a element?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, beautifulsoup

I have a web-scraping code using Selenium-python and realized I don't need to run any javascript so for efficiency purposes I'm "translating" it to urllib.requests and BeautifulSoup. I've got and issue trying to mimic the work done by the ".text" attribute of selenium when reading the tables. BeautifulSoup doesn't seem to have such simple way to read tables. When trying to search in Selenium module how the ".text" attribute is coded I figured I don't know how to look up for such information. Can anyone help me to figure this information. Where is explained how this atribute is retrieved from html?

```
Example_url = "http://www4.tjrj.jus.br/consultaProcessoWebV2/consultaMov.do?v=2&numProcesso=2008.001.000272-2&acessoIP=internet&tipoUsuario="
```

When I do try with Selenium:

```
driver.get(Example_url)

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="content"]/form/table/tbody').text
```

I get the desired result (sample)

"  As informações aqui contidas não produzem efeitos legais.\nSomente a publicação no DJERJ oficializa despachos e decisões e estabelece prazos.\n\nProcesso No 0000184-70.2008.8.19.0001\n2008.001.000272-2\n  TJ/RJ - 16/11/2018 06:50:45\n  ARQUIVADO EM DEFINITIVO - MAÇO Nº 1706, em 02/07/2012\n  Comarca da Capital 11ª Vara Criminal\nCartório da 11ª Vara Criminal\n  Endereço: Av. Erasmo Braga   115   L II sala 504  \nBairro: Centro\nCidade: Rio de Janeiro\n  Ofício de Registro: 3º Ofício de Registro de Distribuição\nAssunto: Furto (Art. 155 - CP) C/C Crime Tentado, II\n  Classe: Ação Penal - Procedimento Ordinário\n  Autor MINISTERIO PUBLICO DO ESTADO DO RIO DE JANEIRO\n  Listar alterações / exclusões de personagens\n  Advogado(s): TJ000002  -  DEFENSOR PÚBLICO\n    Tipo do Movimento: Arquivamento\nData de arquivamento: 02/07/2012\nTipo de arquivamento: definitivo\nMaço: 1706\nMaço recebido pelo arquivo em: 09/07/2012\nLocal de arquivamento: Arquivo Geral - Rio de Janeiro\n  Tipo do Movimento: Revogação da Suspensão do Processo (Art. 89 da Lei 9099)\nData do movimento: 01/07/2012\n  Tipo do Movimento: Ato Ordinatório Praticado\nData: 06/02/2012\nDescrição: Ag. expedição de ofício de baixa. Ofício eletrônico nº 206539271 ao 3º ORD em 14/02/2012., devidamente cumprido em 18/06/2012. Processo para arquivar.\n  Tipo do Movimento: Ato Ordinatório Praticado\nData: 17/01/2012\nDescrição: devolvido da digitação\n  Tipo do Movimento: Digitação de Documentos\nData da digitação: 17/01/2012\n  Tipo do Movimento: Ato Ordinatório Praticado\nData: 06/01/2012\nDescrição: Para fazer comunicações de praxe.\n  Tipo do Movimento: Ato Ordinatório Praticado\nData: 06/01/2012\nDescrição: Certifico que a r. sentença de fls. 111/112, transitou em julgado para as partes em 04/11/2011."...(it continues..)

Comment: It is likely .text is not an attribute but rather is the text content of an element you mean. Can you share your code, url/html and expected result? There are other methods for reading tables easily.

Comment: For making test I would suggest to do it during 20:00 - 11:00 UTC time. Since the page is blocked for robots during day working hours in Brazil.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming javascript doesn't need to run. I will test during hours you indicate.

I would probably try pandas first to retrieve table

```
import pandas as pd
result = pd.read_html("http://www4.tjrj.jus.br/consultaProcessoWebV2/consultaMov.do?v=2&numProcesso=2008.001.000272-2&acessoIP=internet&tipoUsuario=")
print(result[0].dropna()) # <== or choose appropriate index
```

Otherwise, CSS selector to target the table using requests.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'http://www4.tjrj.jus.br/consultaProcessoWebV2/consultaMov.do?v=2&numProcesso=2008.001.000272-2&acessoIP=internet&tipoUsuario='
res  = requests.get(url,headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'lxml')
print(soup.select_one('#content table').text)
```

Answer (score 0):

in my place it ask Captcha, after I solve it in browser then I run `document.cookie` in Console to get the cookie.

```
import requests, re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# simple table formatter
def cleanTable(table):
    table = '\n'.join([x.strip() for x in table.split('\n')])
    table = re.sub(r'(.)[\r\n](.)', r'\1 \2', table)
    table = re.sub(r'[\r\n]{2,}', '\n', table)
    return table.strip()

heads = {'Cookie' : 'JSESSIONID=0afafa3330d816c755a5df3c478cb6388d1b52b9dc5e.e34NbhiLbN0NbO0Lc30PaNaQbN0Me0;'}
Example_url = 'http://www4.tjrj.jus.br/consultaProcessoWebV2/consultaMov.do?v=2&numProcesso=2008.001.000272-2&acessoIP=internet&tipoUsuario='

html = requests.get(Example_url, headers=heads)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find('table').text
# Python 2.7
# table = soup.find('table').text.encode('utf-8')

print(cleanTable(table))
```

Answer (score 0):

A few words about the solution:

- The website `http://www4.tjrj.jus.br/consultaProcessoWebV2/consultaMov.do?v=2&numProcesso=2008.001.000272-2&acessoIP=internet&tipoUsuario=%22` uses *JavaScript*. So `urllib.requests` and `BeautifulSoup` alone may not help us.
- A better approach will be to use *Selenium* to initiate the session and induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be visible*.
- Next you can use *BeautifulSoup* to read the tables.
- The equivalent of `.text` in *BeautifulSoup* is **getText()**
- To achieve your goal, you can use the following solution.
- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

  my_url = 'http://www4.tjrj.jus.br/consultaProcessoWebV2/consultaMov.do?v=2&numProcesso=2008.001.000272-2&acessoIP=internet&tipoUsuario='
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get(my_url)
  WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "form[name='formResultado']")))
  page_soup = soup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
  container = page_soup.find("form",{"name":"formResultado"})
  content = container.getText()
  print(content)
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
              As informações aqui contidas não produzem
              efeitos legais.

              Somente a publicação no DJERJ oficializa
              despachos e decisões e estabelece prazos.




  Processo No
                0000184-70.2008.8.19.0001




  2008.001.000272-2





                TJ/RJ -
                07/12/2018 13:26:09








                      ARQUIVADO EM DEFINITIVO - MAÇO Nº 1706, em 02/07/2012








              Comarca da Capital




              11ª Vara Criminal







              Cartório da 11ª Vara Criminal







  Endereço:

              Av. Erasmo Braga

              115

              L II sala 504




  Bairro:

              Centro



  Cidade:

              Rio de Janeiro






  Ofício de Registro:

              3º Ofício de Registro de Distribuição



  Assunto:

              Furto  (Art. 155 - CP) C/C Crime Tentado, II






  Classe:

              Ação Penal - Procedimento Ordinário







                Autor


                MINISTERIO PUBLICO DO ESTADO DO RIO DE JANEIRO






  Listar alterações / exclusões de personagens








  TIPO
  PERSONAGEM



                      Acusado


                      FABRÍCIO XAVIER LIMA









  Imprimir

                        Fechar










  Advogado(s):


                TJ000002
                 - 
                DEFENSOR PÚBLICO








  Tipo do Movimento:
  Arquivamento


  Data de arquivamento:
  02/07/2012


  Tipo de arquivamento:
  definitivo


  Maço:
  1706


  Maço recebido pelo arquivo em: 
  09/07/2012


  Local de arquivamento:
  Arquivo Geral - Rio de Janeiro



  Tipo do Movimento:
  Revogação da Suspensão do Processo (Art. 89 da Lei 9099)


  Data do movimento:
  01/07/2012



  Tipo do Movimento:
  Ato Ordinatório Praticado


  Data:
  06/02/2012


  Descrição:
  Ag. expedição de ofício de baixa. Ofício eletrônico nº 206539271 ao 3º ORD em 14/02/2012., devidamente cumprido em 18/06/2012. Processo para arquivar.



  Tipo do Movimento:
  Ato Ordinatório Praticado


  Data:
  17/01/2012


  Descrição:
  devolvido da digitação



  Tipo do Movimento:
  Digitação de Documentos


  Data da digitação:
  17/01/2012



  Tipo do Movimento:
  Ato Ordinatório Praticado


  Data:
  06/01/2012


  Descrição:
  Para fazer comunicações de praxe.



  Tipo do Movimento:
  Ato Ordinatório Praticado


  Data:
  06/01/2012


  Descrição:
  Certifico que a r. sentença de fls. 111/112, transitou em julgado para as partes em 04/11/2011.



  Tipo do Movimento:
  Trânsito em Julgado MP


  Data:
  04/11/2011


  Autor:
  MINISTERIO PUBLICO DO ESTADO DO RIO DE JANEIRO


  Tipo do Movimento:
  Recebimento

  Data de Recebimento:
  27/10/2011

  Tipo do Movimento:
  Sentença - Julgado improcedente o pedido

  Data Sentença:
  27/10/2011


  Descrição:
  ...Ante o exposto, JULGO IMPROCEDENTE o pedido para ABSOLVER FABRICIO XAVIER LIMA, com fulcro no artigo 386, III, do CPP...

  Ver íntegra do(a) Sentença






  Tipo do Movimento:
  Conclusão ao Juiz


  Data da conclusão:
  27/10/2011

  Juiz:
  ALCIDES DA FONSECA NETO



  Tipo do Movimento:
  Sentença em Audiência  - Julgado improcedente o pedido


  Juiz:
  ALCIDES DA FONSECA NETO


  Data da sentença:
  27/10/2011


  Descrição:
  No dia 27 de outubro do ano de dois mil e onze, às 13h30min, na sala de audiências da 11ª Vara Criminal, na presença do Doutor Alcides da Fonseca Neto, Juiz de Direito, do Dr. Carlos Gilberto Magalhães, Promotor de Justi...


  Ver íntegra do(a) Sentença






  Tipo do Movimento:
  Audiência Instrução e Julgamento

  Data da audiência:
  27/10/2011


  Resultado:
  Realizada - sentença em audiência


  Descrição:
  No dia 27 de outubro do ano de dois mil e onze, às 13h30min, na sala de audiências da 11ª Vara Criminal, na presença do Doutor Alcides da Fonseca Neto, Juiz de Direito, do Dr. Carlos Gilberto Magalhães, Promotor de Justi...


  Ver íntegra do(a) Audiência Instrução e Julgamento






  Tipo do Movimento:
  Juntada de Mandado


  Data da juntada:
  13/10/2011


  Número do Documento:
  1852/2011/MND


  Resultado:
  Positivo



  Tipo do Movimento:
  Recebidos os autos

  Data do recebimento:
  10/10/2011


  Tipo do Movimento:
  Remessa


  Destinatário:
  Defensor Público


  Data da remessa:
  06/10/2011


  Prazo:
  15 dia(s)



  Tipo do Movimento:
  Ato Ordinatório Praticado


  Data:
  05/10/2011


  Descrição:
  Nesta data, faço vista dos presentes autos à Defensoria Pública.



  Tipo do Movimento:
  Juntada de Mandado


  Data da juntada:
  05/10/2011


  Número do Documento:
  1853/2011/MND


  Resultado:
  Positivo



  Tipo do Movimento:
  Recebidos os autos

  Data do recebimento:
  05/10/2011


  Tipo do Movimento:
  Remessa


  Destinatário:
  Ministério Público


  Data da remessa:
  05/10/2011


  Prazo:
  15 dia(s)



  Tipo do Movimento:
  Ato Ordinatório Praticado


  Data:
  04/10/2011


  Descrição:
  Certifico em relação à FAC acostada às fls. 95/96, o que segue: 

  ANOTAÇÃO 1 DE2 - Refere-se ao processo 0043642-02.2003.8.19.0038 do 1º. JECRIM de N. Iguaçu, no qual foi determinado em 27/09/05 o declínio de competência em favor de uma das varas criminais. Processo baixado em 11/11/05, redistribuído à  7ª V.Criminal onde foi rejeitada à denúncia com fulcro nos arts. 43, II, e 61 do C.P.P. e em sua decorrência n/f dos rts. 107, IV, e 115 do C.P., sendo  DECLARADA EXTINTA A PUNIBILIDADE dos fatos apurados neste procedimento, pela ocorrência do fenômeno da prescrição, por sentença datada 25/01/06 e transitada em 20/03/06. Arquivado com baixa em 15/05/06.

  ANOTAÇÃO 2 DE 2 - ESTES.



  Tipo do Movimento:
  Ato Ordinatório Praticado


  Data:
  13/09/2011


  Descrição:
  Certifico em relação ao despacho de fls. 88, o que se segue: 

  - O acusado foi requisitado, conforme fl. 88;
  - As intimações e requisições necessárias foram expedidas, conforme fls. 97/99; FAC  (fls. 95/96), ESCLARECIDA (fl. 100); 
  - As diligências requeridas pelo MP foram totalmente cumpridas;
  - As testemunhas foram devidamente cadastradas no sistema "DCP".



  Tipo do Movimento:
  Digitação de Carta Precatória


  Data da expedição:
  08/09/2011



  Tipo do Movimento:
  Digitação de Documentos


  Data da digitação:
  08/09/2011


  Tipo do Movimento:
  Recebimento

  Data de Recebimento:
  26/07/2011

  Tipo do Movimento:
  Despacho - Proferido despacho de mero expediente

  Data Despacho:
  22/07/2011


  Descrição:
  ...Assim, com fulcro no artigo 399 da Lei Processual Penal, designo o dia 27/10/2011, às 13horas, para Audiência de Instrução e Julgamento, oportunidade na qual serão tomados os depoimentos das testemunhas arroladas pelo...

  Ver íntegra do(a) Despacho





  Tipo do Movimento:
  Conclusão ao Juiz


  Data da conclusão:
  18/07/2011

  Juiz:
  SIMONE DE FARIA FERRAZ



  Tipo do Movimento:
  Recebidos os autos

  Data do recebimento:
  11/07/2011


  Tipo do Movimento:
  Remessa


  Destinatário:
  Ministério Público


  Data da remessa:
  08/07/2011


  Prazo:
  15 dia(s)



  Tipo do Movimento:
  Ato Ordinatório Praticado


  Data:
  07/07/2011


  Descrição:
  DEVOLVIDO DA DIGITAÇÃO



  Tipo do Movimento:
  Digitação de Documentos


  Data da digitação:
  07/07/2011



  Tipo do Movimento:
  Recebidos os autos

  Data do recebimento:
  22/06/2011


  Tipo do Movimento:
  Remessa


  Destinatário:
  Defensor Público


  Data da remessa:
  22/06/2011


  Prazo:
  15 dia(s)



  Tipo do Movimento:
  Ato Ordinatório Praticado


  Data:
  21/06/2011


  Descrição:
  DILIGENCIAS


  Tipo do Movimento:
  Recebimento

  Data de Recebimento:
  20/06/2011

  Tipo do Movimento:
  Decisão - Revogação da Suspensão do Processo

  Data Decisão:
  16/06/2011


  Descrição:
  Assim, diante do exposto, REVOGO A DECISÃO QUE SUSPENDEU O PROCESSO e DEIXO DE DECLARAR A EXTINÇÃO DA PUNIBILIDADE DO RÉU.

  O réu foi devidamente citado(fls.42/43).

  Portando, remetam-se os autos ao ilustre Defensor ...

  Ver íntegra do(a) Decisão





  Tipo do Movimento:
  Conclusão ao Juiz


  Data da conclusão:
  16/06/2011

  Juiz:
  ALCIDES DA FONSECA NETO



  Tipo do Movimento:
  Recebidos os autos

  Data do recebimento:
  07/06/2011


  Tipo do Movimento:
  Remessa


  Destinatário:
  Ministério Público


  Data da remessa:
  07/06/2011


  Prazo:
  15 dia(s)


  Tipo do Movimento:
  Recebimento

  Data de Recebimento:
  03/06/2011

  Tipo do Movimento:
  Despacho - Despacho

  Data Despacho:
  02/06/2011


  Descrição:
  Dê-se vista ao Ministério Público. Após, venham conclusos.



  Tipo do Movimento:
  Conclusão ao Juiz


  Data da conclusão:
  02/06/2011

  Juiz:
  ALCIDES DA FONSECA NETO


  Tipo do Movimento:
  Recebimento

  Data de Recebimento:
  20/12/2010

  Tipo do Movimento:
  Despacho - Proferido despacho de mero expediente

  Data Despacho:
  17/12/2010


  Descrição:
  Cobre-se a carta precatória de fls.79, devidamente cumprida. Após, venham os autos conclusos.



  Tipo do Movimento:
  Conclusão ao Juiz


  Data da conclusão:
  13/12/2010

  Juiz:
  ALCIDES DA FONSECA NETO



  Tipo do Movimento:
  Despacho em Audiência  - Proferido despacho de mero expediente


  Juiz:
  RODRIGO JOSE MEANO BRITO


  Data do despacho:
  03/12/2010


  Descrição:
  No dia 03 de dezembro do ano de dois mil e dez, às 14h32min, na sala de audiências da 11ª Vara Criminal, na presença do Doutor Alcides da Fonseca Neto, Juiz de Direito, do Dr. Celso de Andrade Loureiro, Promotor de Justi...


  Ver íntegra do(a) Despacho






  Tipo do Movimento:
  Audiência Especial

  Data da audiência:
  03/12/2010


  Resultado:
  Realizada - Despacho em audiência


  Descrição:
  No dia 03 de dezembro do ano de dois mil e dez, às 14h32min, na sala de audiências da 11ª Vara Criminal, na presença do Doutor Alcides da Fonseca Neto, Juiz de Direito, do Dr. Celso de Andrade Loureiro, Promotor de Justi...


  Ver íntegra do(a) Audiência Especial






  Tipo do Movimento:
  Recebidos os autos

  Data do recebimento:
  20/10/2010


  Tipo do Movimento:
  Remessa


  Destinatário:
  Defensor Público


  Data da remessa:
  20/10/2010


  Prazo:
  15 dia(s)



  Tipo do Movimento:
  Recebidos os autos

  Data do recebimento:
  19/10/2010


  Tipo do Movimento:
  Remessa


  Destinatário:
  Ministério Público


  Data da remessa:
  19/10/2010


  Prazo:
  15 dia(s)



  Tipo do Movimento:
  Digitação de Documentos


  Data da digitação:
  18/10/2010


  Tipo do Movimento:
  Recebimento

  Data de Recebimento:
  13/10/2010

  Tipo do Movimento:
  Despacho - Proferido despacho de mero expediente

  Data Despacho:
  27/09/2010


  Descrição:
  Face à certidão, expeça-se carta precatória p/intimação do acusado para participar da audiência neste Juízo. Urgente!!!



  Tipo do Movimento:
  Conclusão ao Juiz


  Data da conclusão:
  24/09/2010

  Juiz:
  ALCIDES DA FONSECA NETO


  Tipo do Movimento:
  Recebimento

  Data de Recebimento:
  25/08/2010

  Tipo do Movimento:
  Despacho - Proferido despacho de mero expediente

  Data Despacho:
  24/08/2010


  Descrição:
  Designo para o dia 03/12/2010, às 14h30min, para realização da Audiência de advertência, nos exatos termos da promoção do Ministério Público.
  Intime-se o acusado.
  Ciência ao Ministério Público e à Drª. Defensora Públic...


  Ver íntegra do(a) Despacho





  Tipo do Movimento:
  Conclusão ao Juiz


  Data da conclusão:
  23/08/2010

  Juiz:
  ALCIDES DA FONSECA NETO



  Tipo do Movimento:
  Ato Ordinatório Praticado


  Data:
  17/08/2010


  Descrição:
  remessa cls



  Tipo do Movimento:
  Recebidos os autos

  Data do recebimento:
  23/07/2010


  Tipo do Movimento:
  Remessa


  Destinatário:
  Ministério Público


  Data da remessa:
  23/07/2010


  Prazo:
  15 dia(s)


  Tipo do Movimento:
  Recebimento

  Data de Recebimento:
  06/07/2010

  Tipo do Movimento:
  Despacho - Despacho

  Data Despacho:
  30/06/2010


  Descrição:
  Dê-se vista ao Ministério Público.



  Tipo do Movimento:
  Conclusão ao Juiz


  Data da conclusão:
  14/06/2010

  Juiz:
  ALCIDES DA FONSECA NETO



  Tipo do Movimento:
  Recebidos os autos

  Data do recebimento:
  10/06/2010


  Tipo do Movimento:
  Remessa


  Destinatário:
  Defensor Público


  Data da remessa:
  09/06/2010


  Prazo:
  15 dia(s)


  Tipo do Movimento:
  Recebimento

  Data de Recebimento:
  03/05/2010

  Tipo do Movimento:
  Despacho - Proferido despacho de mero expediente

  Data Despacho:
  30/04/2010


  Descrição:
  Dê-se vista a Drª.Defensora Pública. Após, à conlusão.



  Tipo do Movimento:
  Conclusão ao Juiz


  Data da conclusão:
  30/04/2010

  Juiz:
  ALCIDES DA FONSECA NETO



  Tipo do Movimento:
  Recebidos os autos

  Data do recebimento:
  19/01/2010


  Tipo do Movimento:
  Remessa


  Destinatário:
  Ministério Público


  Data da remessa:
  15/01/2010


  Prazo:
  15 dia(s)


  Tipo do Movimento:
  Recebimento

  Data de Recebimento:
  18/11/2009

  Tipo do Movimento:
  Despacho - Proferido despacho de mero expediente

  Data Despacho:
  18/11/2009


  Descrição:
  Dê-se vista ao Ministério Público.



  Tipo do Movimento:
  Conclusão ao Juiz


  Data da conclusão:
  18/11/2009

  Juiz:
  ALCIDES DA FONSECA NETO



  Tipo do Movimento:
  Digitação de Documentos


  Data da digitação:
  30/09/2009



  Tipo do Movimento:
  Digitação de Carta Precatória


  Data da expedição:
  22/07/2009


  Tipo do Movimento:
  Recebimento

  Data de Recebimento:
  27/05/2009

  Tipo do Movimento:
  Despacho - Proferido despacho de mero expediente

  Data Despacho:
  27/05/2009


  Descrição:
  Intime-se o acusado para comparecer em cartório, no prazo de cinco dias,  a fim de justificar o não cumprimento assumido na assentada de fls.39, sob pena de revogação do benefício concedido e prosseguimento do feito.



  Tipo do Movimento:
  Conclusão ao Juiz


  Data da conclusão:
  14/05/2009

  Juiz:
  ALCIDES DA FONSECA NETO



  Tipo do Movimento:
  Ato Ordinatório Praticado


  Data:
  03/09/2008


  Descrição:
  PROCESSO INVENTARIADO EM 03/09/08



  Tipo do Movimento:
  Suspensão do Processo (Art. 89 da Lei 9099)


  Data do movimento:
  18/02/2008



  Tipo do Movimento:
  Juntada de Mandado


  Data da juntada:
  18/02/2008


  Número do Documento:
  137/2008/MND


  Resultado:
  Positivo


  Número do Documento:
  9/2008/ALVS


  Resultado:
  Positivo



  Tipo do Movimento:
  Digitação de Documentos


  Data da digitação:
  30/01/2008



  Tipo do Movimento:
  Ato Ordinatório Praticado


  Data:
  30/01/2008


  Descrição:
  Of. para o IFP informando a suspensão



  Tipo do Movimento:
  Digitação de Documentos


  Data da digitação:
  29/01/2008


  Descrição:
  O acusado Fabrício foi posto em liberdade atráves do  ALVS 9/2008  de 29/01/2008, na mesma data.



  Tipo do Movimento:
  Audiência Interrogatório

  Data da audiência:
  29/01/2008


  Resultado:
  Realizada - Suspensão do Processo


  Descrição:
  Aberta a audiência, pediu a palavra o Dr. Promotor de Justiça, para propor a suspensão do processo, o que foi aceito pelo acusado e pela sua ilustre Defensora. A seguir, o MM. Dr. Juiz, proferiu a seguinte decisão.  Ante...


  Ver íntegra do(a) Audiência Interrogatório






  Tipo do Movimento:
  Digitação de Documentos


  Data da digitação:
  21/01/2008


  Tipo do Movimento:
  Recebimento

  Data de Recebimento:
  18/01/2008

  Tipo do Movimento:
  Decisão - Recebimento de Denúncia ou Queixa

  Data Decisão:
  18/01/2008


  Descrição:
  Portanto, recebo a denúncia e designo o dia 29/01/08, às 13h50min, para realização do interrogatório.
  Requisite-se e cite-se o réu.
  Expeça-se mandado de busca e apreensão da FAC. Prazo de 48 horas.
  Ciência ao Ministér...


  Ver íntegra do(a) Decisão





  Tipo do Movimento:
  Conclusão ao Juiz


  Data da conclusão:
  15/01/2008

  Juiz:
  ALCIDES DA FONSECA NETO



  Tipo do Movimento:
  Recebidos os autos

  Data do recebimento:
  14/01/2008


  Tipo do Movimento:
  Remessa


  Destinatário:
  Ministério Público


  Data da remessa:
  10/01/2008


  Prazo:
  15 dia(s)



  Tipo do Movimento:
  Distribuição Sorteio

  Data da distribuição:
  02/01/2008


  Serventia:
  Cartório da 11ª Vara Criminal - 11ª Vara Criminal





  Carta Precatória:



                      0060876-50.2010.8.19.0038




                      0142118-94.2011.8.19.0038








  Processo(s) no Tribunal
                                 de Justiça:

                  Não há.








  Localização
                                         na serventia:

              Arquivo Geral










                Os autos de processos findos terão como
                destinação final a guarda permanente ou
                a eliminação, depois de cumpridos os
                respectivos prazos de guarda definidos na  Tabela de 
                Temporalidade de Documentos do PJERJ.
  ```